# Is done required in async Jest tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs, supertest

I'm having an argument with a co-worker about `done()` in Jest tests.

He's orders of magnitude more experienced with JavaScript than I am, and I came in after `async`/`await` was generally accepted, plus came from a .NET environment, so I was used to it.

I write my tests like this:

```
it("should return 200 OK for POST method", async () => {
    await request(app).post("SOMEENDPOINT")
      .attach("file", "file")
      .expect(200);
});
```

He's more used to promises so will write his tests like this:

```
it("should return 200 OK for POST method", (done) => {
  request(app).post("SOMEENDPOINT")
    .attach("file", "file")
    .expect(200, done);
});
```

He's fine with my push to `async`/`await`, but insists I have to include `done`, such that I'm either doing his version modified version:

```
it("should return 200 OK for POST method", async (done) => {
  await request(app).post("SOMEENDPOINT")
    .attach("file", "file")
    .expect(200, done);
});
```

Or:

```
it("should return 200 OK for POST method", async (done) => {
    const res = await request(app).post("SOMEENDPOINT")
     .attach("file", "file");
    
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    done();
});
```

While I recognize calling `done()` is entirely necessary when it's included as a parameter, I was under the impression it is wholly unnecessary when using `async`/`await` in this context.

Request is `supertest.request`.

My question is, do I need to use `done` at all with `async`/`await`?

Comment: As you can see in the documentation, it's not needed: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await

Comment: That was my original argument as well.

Answer (score 10):

There's never a need for `done` and `async` on the same test function. Pick one or the other, or, in this case, return the promise directly:

```
it("should return 200 OK for POST method", () =>
  request(app).post("SOMEENDPOINT")
    .attach("file", "file")
    .expect(200)
);
```

Jest will `await` any returned promise which means we can always manually construct and return a promise without `async` or `done`. This is redundant since we already have a promise at hand, but the following [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) is possible, if only for illustrative purposes:

```
it("should return 200 OK for POST method", () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(app).post("SOMEENDPOINT")
      .attach("file", "file")
      .expect(200, resolve)
      .catch(err => reject(err))
    ;
  });
});
```

`done` is typically used for testing asynchronous callbacks (think basic Node library utilities in the `fs` module). In these cases, it's more elegant to add the `done` parameter and invoke it in the callback than it is to promisify the callback by hand. Essentially, `done` is a shortcut to promisification that abstracts out the `new Promise` boilerplate shown above.

Note that `done` can accept a parameter which is treated as an error (see the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#callbacks)). This should go into any `catch` blocks to avoid a timeout and confusing error when the main line code throws before calling `done`:

```
it("should return 200 OK for POST method", done => {
  request(app).post("SOMEENDPOINT")
    .attach("file", "file")
    .expect(200, done)
    .catch(err => done(err))
  ;
});
```

Comment: "`async` is sufficient to specify that the function returns a promise, and when it does, Jest knows to `await` on its resolution". Does this mean I can use `await` if I wanted to? Because using `await` doesn't work for me (timeout), and removing it works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, my initial code snippet was incorrect. Fixed.